# Cannot find the element on the page using Xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to obtain prices for the trips between every two stations in Metro North so I wrote the program to webscrape their website. But it does not work as it cannot find the prices on the page.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/miss_evgenia/Desktop/path/chromedriver')
driver.get("http://as0.mta.info/mnr/schedules/sched_form.cfm")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='Vorig_station']"))).click()
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='Vorig_station']"))))
select.select_by_visible_text('ANSONIA')
select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='Vdest_station']"))))
select.select_by_visible_text('WATERBURY')
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='fares']")))
elem.click()
time.sleep(3)
price1 =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contentbox"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').text
price2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contentbox"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]').text
print(price1)
print(price2)
```

The prices are the red circles on the picture:

[image]

Please help me to obtain these two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
On Board: (//td/a[contains(text(), 'One Way Intermediate')]/following::td)[1]
Station: (//td/a[contains(text(), 'One Way Intermediate')]/following::td)[2]
```

All of the cells are too similar, you need to define a starting point and find the correct cell by relation.